# Cypress Wait for List of Rows in View to Appear Before Checking Number of Rows

Tags: angular, cypress

Using Angular I have created the following list view listing rows of replications.
I was required to write a Cypress test case that:

1. checks the # of rows upon initial loading of the replications tab
2. filters the replications and check the # of rows
3. clear the filters and check the # of rows again

The problem is for #1, Cypress would always try to check the count before the list of replications is loaded.  Click the link "The way my application works" below to see the animated .gif

Angular Component code:

```
  <section class="my-3 d-flex">
    <div class="my-auto">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rowCount"></ng-container>
    </div>
...
  </section>
  <section class="my-3">
    <app-list
      data-cy="replicateList"
      [rows]="replicates"
      [loadError]="loadError"
      [rowTemplate]="replicateRow"
      [noRowsTemplate]="noRows"
      [noFilteredRowsTemplate]="noFilteredRows"
      [selectedFn]="isSelectedReplicate"
      [filterFns]="filters"
      [sortFn]="sort"
      (rowsFiltered)="onRowsFiltered($event)"
    >
      <ng-template #replicateRow let-replicate="row" let-index="index" let-selected="selected">
        <app-replicate-list-entry [replicate]="replicate" [index]="index" [selected]="selected"></app-replicate-list-entry>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #noRows>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">{{ 'replicate_list_no_rows' | translate }}</div>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #noFilteredRows>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">{{ 'replicate_list_no_filtered_rows' | translate }}</div>
      </ng-template>
    </app-list>
  </section>
```

[The way my application works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H07OR.gif)

[Cypress test to test the feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ3wY.gif)

From the Cypress test .gif, you can see that we are trying to count the # of rows when the spinner is still loading.  Hence we always get the following null values:

Loading Replications // This should read "79 results" as per the animated .gif; then the Cypress test below would pick up the 79

the number for resAfterFilter is: null

the value of resultInNum at the beginning is: null

My Cypress test code:

```
pageSelected = 'replicateList'


  static countAfterFilter(pageSelected) {
      cy.get('[data-cy=' + pageSelected + ']', { timeout: 1000 }).invoke('text').then((text) => {
        cy.get('[data-cy=\'rowCount\']', { timeout: 10000 }).invoke('text').then((text) => {
          cy.log(text);
          var resultInStr = text;
          var resAfterFilter = (resultInStr.match(/\d+/));
          cy.log("the number for resAfterFilter is : " + resAfterFilter);
          this.filtersAllOffResultInNum = resAfterFilter;
          cy.log("the value of resultInNum at the begining is : " + this.filtersAllOffResultInNum)
        });
    });
  }
```

My unsuccessful attempts to get ensure the list contents are loaded before checking the # of rows in the listview:

```
cy.get('div.spinner-border.m-5', { timeout: 10000 }).should('not.be.visible', { timeout: 10000 }).then(() => {0
```

Failed because Cypress did not find the spinner.

```
cy.get('[data-cy=' + pageSelected + ']', { timeout: 10000 }).find('.listRow', { timeout: 10000}).should('have.length.gt', 0).then(() => {
```

Failed because the length of the list view contents will always be 0 - as list view is loading and we only see the spinner, as per the Cypress animated .gif link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right approach to wait for the rows to appear, because `.should(...)` forces a retry until it's condition is met

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=' + pageSelected + ']', { timeout: 10000 })
  .find('.listRow', { timeout: 10000})
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)
```

but sometimes it's difficult to know if the right things are being retried. Perhaps only the find() is being retried, but not the get().

Try combining the criteria

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=' + pageSelected + ']' + ' .listRow', { timeout: 10000 })
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)
```

Note there's a space in front of the `.listRow` to indicate a descendent element.

Or, using a string template

```js
cy.get(`[data-cy="${pageSelected}"] .listRow`, { timeout: 10000 })
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)
```

The `static countAfterFilter()` indicates you have a Page Object, but that pattern doesn't always work well with Cypress. Start by trying the above code inline in the test, if it works then move it to the Page Object.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the `#noRows` to not exist and then check the number of rows:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="replicateList"]').should('be.visible') //try locating the selector for this element as a pageRender validation
cy.get('#noRows`).should('not.exist') // //try locating the selector for this element as an assertion that the list is present
cy.get('[data-cy=' + pageSelected + ']', { timeout: 1000 
    }).invoke('text').then((text) => {
        cy.get('[data-cy=\'rowCount\']', { timeout: 10000 }).invoke('text').then((text) => {
          cy.log(text);
          var resultInStr = text;
          var resAfterFilter = (resultInStr.match(/\d+/));
          cy.log("the number for resAfterFilter is : " + resAfterFilter);
          this.filtersAllOffResultInNum = resAfterFilter;
          cy.log("the value of resultInNum at the begining is : " + this.filtersAllOffResultInNum)
     });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like `#noRows` is a structural id for the compiler, but does not appear on the web page.

Comment: Try to locate the element that is associated with it and assert it is not existent

Comment: I added some more assertions to my suggestion - you would need to find the associated elements though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @RosenMihaylov's suggestion, might search for whatever text corresponds to `replicate_list_no_rows` in the $translateProvider,

e.g if in English it's

```js
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
  'replicate_list_no_rows': 'There are no rows',
  ...
});
```

use this

```js
cy.contains('div', 'There are no rows').should('not.exist');
```

Then the counter text is just

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="rowCount"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', '46 results')
```

or if you're testing in various languages

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="rowCount"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('contain', '46')    // drop the language dependent text
```