# How to get text from filtered rows td in Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

In my test I have a table which I am filtering by some text. As a result I get an array of rows. My goal is to get a text from certain cell of each row (e.g. td #3). Here is the point where the first row was selected:

```
cy.get('#myTable')
  .find('tbody')
  .find('tr')
  .filter(':not(:contains("some text"))')
  .then(($rows) => {
    console.log($rows[0])
  })
```

I can do this in this way (e.g. for row 0). But it looks ugly and `$rows[0].find('td').eq(3)` doesn't work

```
cy.get('#myTable')
  .find('tbody')
  .find('tr')
  .filter(':not(:contains("Corporate Approved"))')
  .then(($rows) => {
    cy.wrap($rows[0]).find('td').eq(3).then(($cell) => {
      cy.log($cell.text())
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

The code you have is ok except if the table loads asynchronously, then you would need a check to see if the rows are present before testing the cells.

See [Cypress Wait for List of Rows in View to Appear Before Checking Number of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68009952/cypress-wait-for-list-of-rows-in-view-to-appear-before-checking-number-of-rows)

```js
cy.get('#myTable')
  .find('tbody')
  .find('tr')
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)
  .filter(':not(:contains("Corporate Approved"))')
  .first()  
  .then($row => {
    const firstCellText = $row.find('td').eq(1).then($cell => $cell.text())
    const thirdCellText = $row.find('td').eq(3).then($cell => $cell.text())
    console.log(firstCellText, thirdCellText)
  })
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to get and to save the values of the 1st and 3rd td of each filtered row. It doesn't matter for me if this will be achived with jQuery or Cypress commands.  In the code provided by me I didn't find jQuery solution for  the $rows object, so I had to wrap it in Cypress object and then back to lQuery object. It would be better to use Jquery commands for this object to avoid wrapping it. `$rows[0].find()`  doesn't work (maybe because it's  a DOM collection as you mentioned above, but not an array)

Comment: Actually I was mistaken about `$rows[0]`  it is legitimate syntax, it returns the first item in the collection. Did you mention that you needed two cells in the question - if so I missed that. In that case you will need `.then()` callback of some kind.

Comment: The problem may be caused by loading of rows (if loaded from API) in which case `.filter(':not(:contains("Corporate Approved"))')` can be acting too soon, because it will pass even if there are not any rows (yet).

Comment: The point of my queestion was that I am not able to iterate the rows as `$row[i].find('[someSelector]')` doesn't work so I have to wrap it to cypress object. But your solution is for the first row only.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, so let me describe the problem one more time: if you look at my code, you can see that object `$rows` contains all rows of the table and I need to iterate them `$rows[0], $rows[1], $rows[2]` and save the first and the third column value. I am not able to do the last step as `$rows[i].find()` doesn't work despite I can print out `$rows[i]`. But it works if I wrap $rows[i] into cypreess object: `cy.wrap($rows[i]).find()`

Comment: Yes, the question neglects to mention iterating. To iterate rows in Cypress, use `.each()` instead of `.then()`